# how to pass arg to scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter function Parameter

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I want to run [genetic_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) with np.std(ddof=1).
so far I write this code that take std with default ddof which is equal to zero. how to set ddof=1 ?

```
stdv=(generic_filter(albedo, np.std, size=Winsize))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial(np.std, ddof=1)`

```
import functools
stdv=(generic_filter(albedo, functools.partial(np.std, ddof=1), size=Winsize))
```